# Show that $ \ x_ 0 \ $ cannot be an optimal solution

Tags: linear-programming

Consider the LP
maximize
 $ \large z
=
cx \ $
subject to
 $ \ Ax
≤
b \ , 
x
≥
0 \ $
where
$ \ c \ $
is a nonzero vector. Suppose that the point
 $ \ x_
0 \ $
is such that
$ \ Ax_
0
< b \ $
and
$ \ x_
0
>
0 \ $.

Show that
$ \ x_
0 \ $
cannot be an optimal solution.

**Answer:**

Max $ \ Z=cx \ $ subject to $ \ Ax \leq b , \ x \geq 0 \ $

Given $ \ x_0 \ $ satisfying $ \ Ax_0 <b \ $.

Then for $ \ \epsilon >0 \ $ , there exists $ \ x'=x_0+\epsilon \ $ such that $ Ax' \leq b \ , \ x' \geq 0 $

Also,

$ cx_0 \leq cx' \ $

$ \Rightarrow x_0 \ $ is not optimal solution.

**I need confirmation of my work.**

Comment: You would need strictness to show that $x_0$ is not optimal. Try $x_0+t c^T$ for some small $t>0$. Then $c x_0 < c (x_0 + t c^T)$.

Comment: Would $ \ x_0+tc^T \ $ satisfy $ \ Ax \leq b \ $ ?

Comment: Yes, for sufficiently small $t$ because $Ax_0 < b$ so you have room to move a little in any direction.